# Creating pyspark dataframe from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have below list of dictionaries

results =

```
 [
    {
        "type:"check_datatype",
        "kwargs":{
            "table":"cars","column_name":"vin","d_type":"string"
            }
    },
    {
        "type":"check_emptystring",
        "kwargs":{
            "table":"cars","column_name":"vin"
            }
    },
    {
        "type:"check_null",
        "kwargs":{
            "table":"cars","columns":["vin","index"]
            }
    }
]
```

I want to create two different pyspark dataframe with below schema -

[image: Table Schems]

args_id column in results table will be same when we have unique pair of (type,kwargs). This JSON has to be run on a daily basis and hence if it find out same pair of (type,kwargs) again, it should give the same args_id value.

Till now, i have written this code -

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
check_type_results = [[elt['type']] for elt in results]
checkColumns = ['type']
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
checkResultsDF = spark.createDataFrame(data=check_type_results, schema=checkColumns)
checkResultsDF = checkResultsDF.withColumn("time", F.current_timestamp())
checkResultsDF = checkResultsDF.withColumn("args_id", F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())))
checkResultsDF.printSchema()
```

Now, with my code , i am always getting args_id in increasing order which is correct for the first run but if i again run the json on next day or may be on same day and in the json file some  pair of (type,kwargs) comes which has already come before so i should be using the same args_id for that pair.

If some pair (type,kwargs) has no entry in Arguments table, then only i will insert into arguments table but if the pair (type,kwargs) already exists in arguments table, then no insert should happen there.

Once these two dataframes are filled properly, then i want to load them into separate delta tables.

Hashcode column in arguments table is unique identifier for each "kwargs".

Answer (score 0):

### Issues

Your schema is a bit incomplete. A more detailed schema will allow you to take advantage of more spark features. See Solution below using `spark-sql` and `pyspark`. Instead of window functions that require ordered partitions, you may take advantage of a few of the table generating array functions such as `explode` and `posexplode` available in `spark-sql`. As it pertains to writing to your delta table, you may see examples [here](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-batch.html)

### Solution 1 : Using Spark SQL

#### Setup

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType,StructType, StructField, StringType, MapType
from pyspark.sql import Row, SparkSession

sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("Demo").getOrCreate()
```

#### Schema Definition

Your sample record is an Array of Structs/Objects where the `kwargs` is a `Maptype` with optional keys. NB. The `True` indicates optional and should assist when there are missing keys or entries with different formats

```py
schema = StructType([
    StructField("entry",ArrayType(
        StructType([
            StructField("type",StringType(),True),
            StructField("kwargs",MapType(StringType(),StringType()),True)
        ])
    ),True)
])
```

#### Reproducible Example

```py
result_entry =[
    {
        "type":"check_datatype",
        "kwargs":{
            "table":"cars","column_name":"vin","d_type":"string"
            }
    },
    {
        "type":"check_emptystring",
        "kwargs":{
            "table":"cars","column_name":"vin"
            }
    },
    {
        "type":"check_null",
        "kwargs":{
            "table":"cars","columns":["vin","index"]
            }
    }
]

df_results = sparkSession.createDataFrame([Row(entry=result_entry)],schema=schema)
df_results.createOrReplaceTempView("df_results")
df_results.show()
```

***Results***

```
+--------------------+
|               entry|
+--------------------+
|[{check_datatype,...|
+--------------------+
```

#### Results Table Generation

I've used `current_date` to capture the current date however you may change this based on your pipeline.

```py
results_table = sparkSession.sql("""
WITH raw_results as (
    SELECT 
        posexplode(entry),
        current_date as time
    FROM
        df_results
)
SELECT
    col.type as Type,
    time,
    pos as arg_id
FROM
    raw_results
""")

results_table.show()
```

***Results***

```
+-----------------+----------+------+
|             Type|      time|arg_id|
+-----------------+----------+------+
|   check_datatype|2021-03-31|     0|
|check_emptystring|2021-03-31|     1|
|       check_null|2021-03-31|     2|
+-----------------+----------+------+
```

#### Arguments Table Generation

```py
args_table = sparkSession.sql("""
WITH raw_results as (
    SELECT 
        posexplode(entry)
    FROM
        df_results
),
raw_arguments AS (
    SELECT
        explode(col.kwargs),
        pos as args_id
    FROM
        raw_results
),
raw_arguments_before_array_check AS (
SELECT
    args_id,
    key as bac_key,
    value as bac_value
    
FROM
    raw_arguments
),
raw_arguments_after_array_check AS (
SELECT
   args_id,
   bac_key,
   bac_value,
   posexplode(split(regexp_replace(bac_value,"[\\\[\\\]]",""),","))
FROM
   raw_arguments_before_array_check
)
SELECT
    args_id,
    bac_key as key,
    col as value,
    CASE
        WHEN bac_value LIKE '[%' THEN pos
        ELSE NULL
    END as list_index,
    abs(hash(args_id, bac_key,col,pos)) as hashcode
FROM
    raw_arguments_after_array_check
""")

args_table.show()
```

***Results***

```
+-------+-----------+------+----------+----------+
|args_id|        key| value|list_index|  hashcode|
+-------+-----------+------+----------+----------+
|      0|     d_type|string|      null| 216841494|
|      0|column_name|   vin|      null| 502458545|
|      0|      table|  cars|      null|1469121505|
|      1|column_name|   vin|      null| 604007568|
|      1|      table|  cars|      null| 784654488|
|      2|    columns|   vin|         0|1503105124|
|      2|    columns| index|         1| 454389776|
|      2|      table|  cars|      null| 858757332|
+-------+-----------+------+----------+----------+
```

### Solution 2: Using UDF

You may also define user-defined-functions with your already implemented python logic and apply this with spark

#### Setup

We will define our functions to create our results and arguments table here. I have chosen to create generator type functions but this is optional.

```py
result_entry =[
    {
        "type":"check_datatype",
        "kwargs":{
            "table":"cars","column_name":"vin","d_type":"string"
            }
    },
    {
        "type":"check_emptystring",
        "kwargs":{
            "table":"cars","column_name":"vin"
            }
    },
    {
        "type":"check_null",
        "kwargs":{
            "table":"cars","columns":["vin","index"]
            }
    }
]

import json
result_entry_str = json.dumps(result_entry)
result_entry_str

def extract_results_table(entry,current_date=None):
    if current_date is None:
        from datetime import date
        current_date = str(date.today())
    if type(entry)==str:
        import json
        entry = json.loads(entry)

    for arg_id,arg in enumerate(entry):
        yield {
            "Type":arg["type"],
            "time":current_date,
            "args_id":arg_id
        }

def extract_arguments_table(entry):
    if type(entry)==str:
        import json
        entry = json.loads(entry)

    for arg_id,arg in enumerate(entry):
        if "kwargs" in arg:
            for arg_entry in arg["kwargs"]:
                orig_key,orig_value = arg_entry, arg["kwargs"][arg_entry]
                if type(orig_value)==list:
                    for list_index,value in enumerate(orig_value):
                        yield {
                            "args_id":arg_id,
                            "key":orig_key,
                            "value":value,
                            "list_index":list_index,
                            "hash_code": hash((arg_id,orig_key,value,list_index))
                        }
                else:
                    yield {
                            "args_id":arg_id,
                            "key":orig_key,
                            "value":orig_value,
                            "list_index":None,
                            "hash_code": hash((arg_id,orig_key,orig_value,"null"))
                        }
```

#### Pyspark Setup

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf,col,explode
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,IntegerType,StringType, ArrayType

results_table_schema = ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField("Type",StringType(),True),
    StructField("time",StringType(),True),
    StructField("args_id",IntegerType(),True)
]),True)

arguments_table_schema = ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField("args_id",IntegerType(),True),
    StructField("key",StringType(),True),
    StructField("value",StringType(),True),
    StructField("list_index",IntegerType(),True),
    StructField("hash",StringType(),True)
]),True)

extract_results_table_udf = udf(lambda entry,current_date=None : [*extract_results_table(entry,current_date)],results_table_schema)
extract_arguments_table_udf = udf(lambda entry: [*extract_arguments_table(entry)],arguments_table_schema)

# this is useful if you intend to use your functions in spark-sql
sparkSession.udf.register('extract_results_table',extract_results_table_udf)
sparkSession.udf.register('extract_arguments_table',extract_arguments_table_udf)
```

#### Spark Data Frame

```py
df_results_1 = sparkSession.createDataFrame([Row(entry=result_entry_str)],schema="entry string")
df_results_1.createOrReplaceTempView("df_results_1")
df_results_1.show()
```

#### Extracting Results Table

```py
# Using Spark SQL
sparkSession.sql("""
WITH results_table AS (
    select explode(extract_results_table(entry)) as entry FROM df_results_1
)
SELECT entry.* from results_table
""").show()
# Just python
df_results_1.select(
   explode(extract_results_table_udf(df_results_1.entry)).alias("entry")
).selectExpr("entry.*").show()
```

***Output***

```
+-----------------+----------+-------+
|             Type|      time|args_id|
+-----------------+----------+-------+
|   check_datatype|2021-03-31|      0|
|check_emptystring|2021-03-31|      1|
|       check_null|2021-03-31|      2|
+-----------------+----------+-------+

+-----------------+----------+-------+
|             Type|      time|args_id|
+-----------------+----------+-------+
|   check_datatype|2021-03-31|      0|
|check_emptystring|2021-03-31|      1|
|       check_null|2021-03-31|      2|
+-----------------+----------+-------+
```

#### Extracting Results Table

```py
# Using spark sql
sparkSession.sql("""
WITH arguments_table AS (
    select explode(extract_arguments_table(entry)) as entry FROM df_results_1
)
SELECT entry.* from arguments_table
""").show()
# Just python
df_results_1.select(
   explode(extract_arguments_table_udf(df_results_1.entry)).alias("entry")
).selectExpr("entry.*").show()
```

***Output***

```
+-------+-----------+------+----------+----+
|args_id|        key| value|list_index|hash|
+-------+-----------+------+----------+----+
|      0|      table|  cars|      null|null|
|      0|column_name|   vin|      null|null|
|      0|     d_type|string|      null|null|
|      1|      table|  cars|      null|null|
|      1|column_name|   vin|      null|null|
|      2|      table|  cars|      null|null|
|      2|    columns|   vin|         0|null|
|      2|    columns| index|         1|null|
+-------+-----------+------+----------+----+

+-------+-----------+------+----------+----+
|args_id|        key| value|list_index|hash|
+-------+-----------+------+----------+----+
|      0|      table|  cars|      null|null|
|      0|column_name|   vin|      null|null|
|      0|     d_type|string|      null|null|
|      1|      table|  cars|      null|null|
|      1|column_name|   vin|      null|null|
|      2|      table|  cars|      null|null|
|      2|    columns|   vin|         0|null|
|      2|    columns| index|         1|null|
+-------+-----------+------+----------+----+
```

### Reference

- [Spark SQL Functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html)
- [Delta Batch Writes](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-batch.html)